# explain these Linq Codes

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
public class Person {
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
}
```

and the call is:

```
var persons = new List<Person>();
persons.Add(new Person {First = "First 04", Last = "Last 04"});
persons.Add(new Person {First = "First 03", Last = "Last 03"});
persons.Add(new Person {First = "First 02", Last = "Last 02"});
persons.Add(new Person {First = "First 01", Last = "Last 01"});

var claim1 = new List<Person>(from c in persons select c);
var claim2 = new List<Person>(persons);
```

what is the difference or the advantage of using this statement

```
var claim1 = new List<Person>(from c in persons select c);
```

over this statement.

```
var claim2 = new List<Person>(persons);
```

Comment: What makes you think those are different? I mean, they *are* insofar as the former has an extra layer through which all the data is passed. But the result is equivalent by definition.

Comment: Effectively, there is none. Constructor `List(IEnumerable<Person> src)` is invoked each time. The difference is that in the first case, you're wrapping your list (which is already `IEnumerable<Person>`) in an `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator` which does a unit transform (i.e. nothing) over each item. Without further clauses in the linq statement, it's a waste using it.

Comment: @spender you comment are the best answer you should put it in an answer section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In first case `from c in persons select c` returns `IEnumerable<Person>`, in the second: `List<Person>()` but in both cases `public List(IEnumerable<T> collection)` is called, so there is no real difference between those two statements.

If disassemble the constructor:

```
public List(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    if (collection == null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.collection);
    }
    ICollection<T> collection2 = collection as ICollection<T>;
    if (collection2 == null)
    {
        this._size = 0;
        this._items = List<T>._emptyArray;
        using (IEnumerator<T> enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                this.Add(enumerator.Current);
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    int count = collection2.Count;
    if (count == 0)
    {
        this._items = List<T>._emptyArray;
        return;
    }
    this._items = new T[count];
    collection2.CopyTo(this._items, 0);
    this._size = count;
}
```

we can see, if `collection` is `ICollection<T>`, `ICollection<T>.CopyTo` is called which is more efficient than copying one by one.

Answer (score 4):

Well both codes create a new list. In the first approach you create it from an IEnumerable collection you get from that linq expression, while in the second you use the List directly. I don't believe there's much of a difference, but I consider the first one a bad practice, because it makes the code harder to comprehend, harder to read and harder to maintain.